# How to match a queue of K students to N examiners

Tags: algorithm

Let us assume that we have N examiners and a queue of k students . The time that each examiner i needs in order to examine a student is stored at A[i].
Our task is to find the total time required in order to examine all students and the examiner that will examine the last student of the queue.Each examiner can examine only one student at a time .Additional restriction:In case more than 1 examiner is not occupied with a student ,the next student goes to the first possible examiner (see step 4 of example)

To give an example , if we have N=2 examiners and k=4 students and the first examiner needs 10 minutes for each student (A[1]=10) and the second examiner needs 5 minutes for each student (A[2]=5) , then :

step 1:student 1 goes to examiner 1 at time 0

step 2:student 2 goes to examiner 2 also at time 0

step 3:student 3 goes to examiner 2 at time 5 ,because student 2 has finished

step 4:student 4 can go either to examiner 1 or examiner 2 at time 10 ,because both have finished.Due to our additional restriction ,he goes to examiner 1

step 5:Student 4 finishes at time 20

So the program should return as output : time= 20 ,examiner =1

So far , I have thought of an O(nk) algorithm:

```
if(n>=k)  //if examiners more than students ,it's simple
{
for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
B[i]=A[i];
p=max_position(B);  //find maximum of first k elements
printf("%d,B[p]);   //required time
return(k);  //kth student goes to kth examiner
}
else
{
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
B[i]=A[i];    //create copy of A
int t=0;
for(i=1;i<=k-n;i++)  //n students already gone to examiners in time 0
{
int p = min_position(B);  //finds position of minimum element
B[p]=B[p]+A[p];
time = B[p];
}
printf("%d ,time);
return(p);
}
```

Is there a way to do it faster than O(nk)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an order to all examiners at any time in a way that:

1. An examiner that becomes available earlier is "smaller" than one that becomes available later. (This can be represented as the time the examiner becomes free)
2. If two examiners become available at the same time, the one that has the smaller index is "smaller".

Using this order you can then construct a min heap storing all examiners and for each student pull the examiner in the top of the heap (the smallest), and insert it then back to the heap adding the time it needs to conduct the exam.

This solution will run in O(klogn).